# Ansible read ansible_ssh_private_key_file from variable

Tags: ansible

I am adding a host using add_host

```
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        ssh_key: "{{ lookup('file','jenkins.pem')| replace('\n','') }}"
    - add_host:
        hostname: tower
        ansible_ssh_host: x.x.x.x
        ansible_ssh_user: jenkins
        ansible_ssh_private_key_file: "{{ ssh_key }}"
    - command: ls /tmp
      delegate_to: tower
```

The above works fine, if I specify a file path for ansible_ssh_private_key_file. But I want to read the ansible_ssh_private_key_file from a variable, it is not working. Is there any way to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a misunderstanding: `lookup("file")` returns the **contents** of a file, but -- as its name is a giveaway -- `ansible_ssh_private_key_file` wants the path on the controller node to the ssh private key **file**, not its contents.

You can use the `lookup("fileglob", "jenkins.pem", wantlist=True) | first` to obtain the path to that `jenkins.pem` file, if you don't already have it, since I believe ansible wants that `ssh_private_key_file` path as fully qualified.